# Swift 2 : AVAssetReader and NSInputStream Audio Graph

Tags: ios, avfoundation, swift2, nsinputstream, avassetreader

I'm trying to convert an example from Bob McCune's Learning AVFoundation book and having some issues using AVAssetReader and NSInputStream. The graph should be a pure sine wave but the values seem reflected on the X-axis somehow.

I've tried every iteration of byte swapping I could think of and that didn't work.

Playground posted to github here:
https://github.com/justinlevi/AVAssetReader

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import XCPlayground

func plotArrayInPlayground<T>(arrayToPlot:Array<T>, title:String) {
  for currentValue in arrayToPlot {
    XCPCaptureValue(title, value: currentValue)
  }
}

class SSSampleDataFilter {
  var sampleData:NSData?

  init(data:NSData) {
    sampleData = data
  }

  func filteredSamplesForSize(size:CGSize) -> [Int]{
    var filterSamples = [UInt16]()

    if let sampleData = sampleData {
      let sampleCount = sampleData.length
      let binSize = CGFloat(sampleCount) / size.width

      let stream = NSInputStream(data: sampleData)
      stream.open()

      var readBuffer = Array<UInt8>(count: 16 * 1024, repeatedValue: 0)
      var totalBytesRead = 0

      let size = sizeof(UInt16)
      while (totalBytesRead < sampleData.length) {
        let numberOfBytesRead = stream.read(&readBuffer, maxLength: size)
        let u16: UInt16 = UnsafePointer<UInt16>(readBuffer).memory

        var sampleBin = [UInt16]()
        for _ in 0..<Int(binSize) {
          sampleBin.append(u16)
        }

        filterSamples.append(sampleBin.maxElement()!)
        totalBytesRead += numberOfBytesRead
      }

      //plotArrayInPlayground(filterSamples, title: "Samples")
    }

    return [0]

  }
}

let sineURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("440.0-sine", withExtension: "aif")!
let asset = AVAsset(URL: sineURL)
var assetReader:AVAssetReader

do{
  assetReader = try AVAssetReader(asset: asset)
}catch{
  fatalError("Unable to read Asset: \(error) : \(__FUNCTION__).")
}

let track = asset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio).first
let outputSettings: [String:Int] =
  [ AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatLinearPCM),
    AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: 0,
    AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: 0,
    AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16,
    AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved: 0]

let trackOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: track!, outputSettings: outputSettings)

assetReader.addOutput(trackOutput)
assetReader.startReading()

var sampleData = NSMutableData()

while assetReader.status == AVAssetReaderStatus.Reading {
  if let sampleBufferRef = trackOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer() {
    if let blockBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer(sampleBufferRef) {
      let bufferLength = CMBlockBufferGetDataLength(blockBufferRef)
      var data = NSMutableData(length: bufferLength)
      CMBlockBufferCopyDataBytes(blockBufferRef, 0, bufferLength, data!.mutableBytes)
      var samples = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int16>(data!.mutableBytes)
      sampleData.appendBytes(samples, length: bufferLength)
      CMSampleBufferInvalidate(sampleBufferRef)
    }
  }
}

let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 375.0, 667.0))
//view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

if assetReader.status == AVAssetReaderStatus.Completed {
  print("complete")

  let filter = SSSampleDataFilter(data: sampleData)
  let filteredSamples = filter.filteredSamplesForSize(view.bounds.size)
}

//XCPShowView("Bezier Path", view: view)
XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely(true)
```

Here's what the graph should look like (taken from Audacity)
[image: Sine wave graph of audio file]

Here's what the graph looks like in the playground

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately your playground doesn't render anything for me in Xcode7b5, however you're asking the `AVAssetReaderTrackOutput` to give you signed 16bit ints, yet your code treats them as unsigned `UInt16`s (and your Audacity file uses floats).

Changing all instances of `UInt16` to `Int16` in your playground seems to print sensible looking sinusoidal data.

Comment: Odd that it didn't render in Xcode7b5 for you. Did you grab the version from github that included the AIFF audio file? Sure enough, as soon as I changed all instances of `UInt16` to 'Int16` everything seems to be working.

Comment: Stared at that for hours yesterday. Thank you

Comment: Follow up question though - Any idea why aif, caf, m4a all work fine but an mp3 version of the same audio does not? I need to go back to the docs and see if I can understand why but I though the AVassetReader took care of the mp3 compression as well

Comment: What happens with mp3?

Comment: Hard to say in the playground but the error is "Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).

Seems to be working fine in an iOS project that I'll post to my github account though so seems like it's not worth figuring out :) Thanks again.